# Read file form txt and perform operation by name in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt similar to that [txt](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4e2rrhg4nb8onwu/checks.txt) but with more lines.

I want to ask for a directory of the main folder that contains the subfolders that each contain the `ASTIK.shp` in the `ASTIK` subfolder, then the `EAS.shp`, in the `EAS` subfolder then the `ASTOM.shp`, etc

`INT` means to perform an intersection with this code where in this case should involve `ASTIK` and `EAS` shapefiles.

for example the line:

```
INT_ASTIK_EAS
```

implies:

```
import geopandas
inte_s=gpd.overlay(ASTIK,EAS,how='intersection')
```

Then go the to the other line and 'catch on' the meaning of the line and perform erase(difference) between the two named shapefiles.

if there is the ER in front of the file names like:

```
ER_ASTOM_ASTIK
```

it should perform:

```
 er=gpd.overlay(ASTOM,ASTIK,how='difference')
```

then finds the exact files and performs it. How do i do that without making a lot of conditions and line by line: like

```
directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
txtfile=open(input()) #insert directory of txt
x = txtfile.readlines()
txtfile.close()
```

this finds the directories that have shps in general in the path that the user will give:

```
import os
import fiona
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = [] # a list with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles.append(fiona.open(filepath))
```

and then somehow
connects the words in the txt to the corresponding calculations(either intersection or difference) with the files mentioned.

From a code like:(i know false but just to give an idea)

```
    If 'INT' in firstline of txt in directory and ASTOM and EAS:
        perform intersection between those.
```

i don't think the only way is to create hundreads of `if` conditions that will probably never be valid.

How should i do the whole thing work?

There is high possibility that a file mentioned in the txt is missing.My bad for not mentioning it.it requires exception and declaration that this specific file is missing.

If you have to suggest changes in the logic or existing code, do so.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you transform your shape list into a dict:

```
import os
import fiona
rootdir = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a' # path to your root directory you walk
sfiles = {} # a dictionary with all the .shp files
for entry in os.listdir(rootdir):
    dirpath = os.path.join(rootdir, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(dirpath): 
        for file in os.listdir(dirpath): # Get all files in the subdirectories
            if file.endswith('.shp'): # If it's an .shp.
                filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
                sfiles[filepath[:-4]] = fiona.open(filepath)
```

then you make an action dict like this:

```
action_dict = {'INT': 'intersection', 'ER': 'difference'}
```

and later in your code

```
directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()

results = []
for line in x:
    action, shape1, shape2 = line.split('_')  # here line is ER_ASTOM_ASTIK or whatever line in your txt file
    if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles:
        results.append(gpd.overlay(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], how=action_dict[action]))
```

Comment: the idea of action_dict1 looks great. Can you tell me how to make it connect with the actual txt and perform as it should?Now it says:`NameError: name 'line' is not defined
` and in general` i don't know where to continue from

Comment: i thought it was obvious. sorry

Comment: It looks correct, but it doesn't show any result.Maybe store each action in a new variable ?What do you suggest, i have to do further process with each outcome from every line.

Comment: i am trying to figure out what's wrong and i see that `sfiles` contains the attributes of the shapefiles and not the shapefiles themselves, how do i make it run?That's why it doesn't proceed with the `action` in the last line.

Comment: here again i thought it was obvious how you could store the results, sorry. for the sfiles problem i used your script exactly as it was. i don't even know what fiona is. i'm helping you on the pure python part. if you have problem with the packages you are using you should ask new questions for that

Comment: it stores nothing because it can't find the `shape1` and `2` in `sfiles` although these files exist.What's wrong?it doesn't perform the intersection